# connect PostgreSQL DB and php

Tags: php

I inastall php 5.4, apache and postgresql 9.2 on Windows 7 OS.

Now, I am trying connect to postgresql DB from php file, this is php connect code:

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres password=pass");
```

This gives: `Call to undefined function pg_connect()`

In `php.ini` file I have: `extension="path\to\extension\php_pgsql.dll"`

What may causes this error?

Comment: Anything useful at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438059/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-pg-connect ?

Comment: I have `extension="path\to\extension\php_pgsql.dll` in php.ini file. This extension exists on specified path. After restarting apache webserver, I see phpinfo() and there is not info about `pgsql`. What I must do also? I am missing something?

Comment: `libpq.dll` and other dependencies must be in the PATH of apache's environment.

Comment: Is the `php.ini` file you are talking about is the one loaded by PHP ? You can see that on the `phpinfo()` page.

Answer (score -1):

I too have tried to connect to a database using pg_connect but I am getting Error: call to undefined function. I have used PDO to connect to database. This seems to work.

```
<?php
try {
$dbuser = 'postgres';
$dbpass = 'your password';
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname='dbname';
$connec = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
}catch (PDOException $e) {
echo "Error : " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
die();
}
?>
```