# Call to undefined function pg_connect() - Wamp

Tags: php, apache, postgresql, wamp, wampserver

I want to connect to PostgreSQL, Im using wamp 64 bit.

I have here

- Apache  2.4.2
- PHP 5.4.3
- Mysql 5.5.24

I also uncomment in php.ini the php_pgsql and php_pdo_pgsql. but i can't connect , It gives me error like this :

Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect()

Is there anybody know the solution regarding on my problem.
I just need it badly.

Thank you .

Comment: Did you restart apache?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg\_connect()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438059/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-pg-connect)

Comment: i restart my apache nothing happen @LawrenceCherone

Comment: You didn't mention libpq.dll. The php dlls can't be loaded without it. See this other duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849010

Answer (score 24):

1. Open php.ini
2. Find `;extension=php_pgsql.dll` and remove the semicolon at the beginning
3. Find `;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll` and remove the semicolon at the beginning
4. Save the file
5. Restart apache

Hope this helps

Comment: You also need to uncomment the line: extension="pgsql.so"

Comment: Excellent. This was the only thing I needed to do. I was trying to connect to a remote PostgreSQL and this method worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

i Solve my problem in putting a LoadFile in httpd.conf

LoadFile "location\libpq.dll";

First i uncomment the extension=php_pgsql.dll and extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
then i put the LoadFile in httpd.conf then restart Apache and Wamp.

Thank you guy's

Answer (score 4):

I think this will help you.

1. Right click on my computer and select properties.
2. Click on advance system settings
3. On the system properties window click “environment variables”
4. Look for system variables frame and click “Path” variable
5. Click the “edit” button
6. Change the variable value by adding your php root path. Mine looks like this:

   > %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\

   Just added your php root path at the end.
7. Restart your wampserver and check mark the `pdo_pgsql` and `php_pgsql` extension using the wamp server menu or by editing your php.ini ; just remove the remark for the above extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Copy `libpq.dll` from php folder (ex.: `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12`) to apache bin folder (ex.: `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin`) then restart apache and be happy!

Answer (score 0):

In case any of that doesnt work, try this in your httpd.conf file under apache...

## configure the path to php.ini

PHPIniDir "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12"