# Connecting CodeIgniter 3.0.6 with PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter-3

I am trying to connect CodeIgniter 3.0.6 with PostgreSQL, and am using an Apache HTTP server with PHP 7.0.5. I looked for some solution in the forums but I did not find anything about it.

Here is the database configuration:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'db_name',
    'dbdriver' => 'postgre',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE,
    'port' => 5432
);
```

The error message is as follows:

> **An uncaught Exception was encountered**
>
> Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined function `pg_connect()`
>
> Filename: E:\xampp\htdocs\facturacion\system\database\drivers\postgre\postgre_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 155

[Image of exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meUpK.jpg)

Comment: A seach for the error messa<ge in this site gives you tons of info, eg see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907868/call-to-undefined-function-pg-connect-wamp  BTW You are showign a password in your error image, don't do that  ever.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it