Cockroachdb pg_connect()
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function pg_connect()

I'm using php8 and apache2.4 server, cockroachdb as cloud database. now I have uncommented these already: extension=pdo_pgsql, extension=pgsql, and set extension_dir = "C:\php\ext" already but it didn't work. Now I tried to uncomment other extensions like (extension=odbc, extension=openssl etc.) and they worked. I think extensio is working but not only with extension=pdo_pgsql and extension=pgsql. Do I need to install postgresql app? Please help I tried everything I can do to solve this and went several forums too. TIA.

In PHP, module load errors are soft errors. There should be log lines indicating what went wrong, but the application won't fail until it attempts to use the module by calling pg_connect().
The pdo_pgsql module has a dependency on the libpq.dll. I downloaded a windows build of PHP from https://windows.php.net/download/. The zip contained libpq.dll, but it was in the root of the zip instead of the ext directory, which may be why adding "C:\php\ext" to the path was not enough resolve the module.
This stack overflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7438157/27343987 includes windows specific instructions for troubleshooting the pg module
