# PHP PDO Mysql not loading. extension is in extensions.ini, php_mysql.so exists, but phpinfo only shows sqlite and dblib

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to get the mysql php pdo to work on FreeBSD 9.1.

Mysql version: 5.5.28
PHP Version: 5.4.7

Applicable Contents of Extensions.ini:

```
extension=pdo_dblib.so
extension=mysql.so
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
```

PHP Info:

PDO support enabled
PDO drivers dblib, sqlite

PDO Driver for FreeTDS/Sybase DB-lib    enabled
Flavour freetds

PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x   enabled
SQLite Library  3.7.14.1

---

So, no pdo_mysql.so being loaded, even though the file exists, its in the extensions file etc.  I've even tried commenting out the pdo.so and mdo_sqlite.so just to make sure the correct extension file was being loaded and for certain... It is.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: have you looked at the error logs? there should be an error in the log if there is a problem loading an extension

Comment: Try changing the  `extension_dir` parameter: [PDO drivers no value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086859/pdo-drivers-no-value)

Comment: I took Patrick's advice and looked at the apache log in /var/log/httpd-error.log.  It was complaining that pdo could not be loaded due to it being built not in release mode. (Not debug).  I opted to remove debugging from my php installation and changed the configuration of php to no debug. made clean ; made deinstall ; make distclean on php5, php5-extensions and php5-pdo_mysql and remade them all.  Got it to work.

Answer (score 3):

- Check which php.ini loaded and if it is the same one you are modifying.
  on cli, do:

`php -i | head |grep -i loaded`

Or in some dummy php file:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

and then open that dummy file in the browser

- Make sure the php mysql support package is installed.

search for it (I am using ubuntu):

`apt-cache search php5*|grep mysql`

Install it (mine happened to be php5-mysql and i think yours would be the same too):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

check again after installing it if you get what you want :)