# httpd.conf deleted - now I can't load PDO driver

Tags: php, pdo, apache2.4

I deleted my httpd.conf by accident.

I am trying to make a working httpd.conf again based on the default file.

I definitely haven't changed php.ini or any environment variables etc, but now my php doesn't seem to be able to use PDO (any new PDO() causes a PDOException).

Also, when I run phpinfo() I get these:

```
PDO support    enabled
PDO drivers    no value
```

I've tried this possible solution: [PDO drivers no value in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086859/pdo-drivers-no-value-in-windows) but it doesn't work for my case.

Is there any other solution? And what could I be missing from httpd.conf that could cause this?

My new httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule php7_module "c:/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

ServerRoot "c:/Apache24"

LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so

#required modules for SSL (HTTPS):
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs/public"
<Directory "c:/Apache24/htdocs/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
LogLevel notice

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "c:/Apache24/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "c:/Apache24/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule headers_module>
    RequestHeader unset Proxy early
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
</IfModule>

<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Post your new httpd.conf.

Comment: ok, I edited my post to include it