# Connecting to MS SQL Server with PHP got an error

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

My current company uses SQL Server as their database. I already installed MS SQL Server Management Studio on my machine. I use xampp.

*My xampp control panel version is 3.2.2*

*My PHP Version is 7.2.12*

*In my phpinfo the driver was not loaded :(

**What I have tried so far:**

1) I added to my php extension `php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll` and declare it to my `php.ini` as `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64`

**Here's my code in php:**

```
<?php

$serverName = "DESKTOP-LPQGPQK\MSSQL14";  

/* Connect using Windows Authentication. */    
try  
{  
$conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database=testdb", "sa","kert");  
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
}  
catch(Exception $e)  
{   
  die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) );   
}
```

The output in my `localhost\phpdev` is: `could not find driver1`

Comment: can you confirm `phpinfo()` if the driver is loaded

Comment: @kenzotenma The driver is not loaded :(

Comment: are you sure, have you downloaded the driver and placed it into extensions directory before updating `php.ini`

Comment: Yes sir, I do it a lot of times. :(

Comment: Have you tried restarting apache?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO drivers no value in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086859/pdo-drivers-no-value-in-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You downloaded a 64bit php pdo sqlsrv dll. But using a 32-bit version xampp. Have both in same bit.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is I am using a 32bit version of xampp, and I downloaded a 64bit php pdo sqlsrv dll.